# Creating Flowcharts in the Office Suite

Tags: microsoft-office, charts, diagrams

I need to create a couple of flowcharts and I am wondering which of the Microsft Office products are best suited to doing so (Word, Powerpoint, Excel?). Do any/all of these have flowchart creation features, and if so how do I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word & Powerpoint will let you create crude flowcharts just by using the drawing toolbar.  However for anything more than 2 or three boxes you need Visio, kind of part of Office but not included in any of the suites.

See the Microsoft page for more info http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/visio/default.aspx or select a free alternative from http://alternativeto.net/desktop/microsoft-visio/

Answer (score 2):

Although not part of the standard Office Suite, [Microsoft Office Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) is probably the product you are looking for.  It is designed for drawing diagrams and charts.  It looks like from there website they have a free online demo, or you can download a 60-day trial version to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Visio is your best bet as far as MS Office products are concerned, but that is not saying anything. I use Visio, but it is definitely not a preference. I would recommend looking at alternative products which can satisfy your needs (and there are also plenty of freebies out there which will be more than adequate).